# Matlab Infinity testing

Tags: testing, matlab, infinite

How i can test a given value is `infinity`, `-infinity` or `NaN.` 
`isinf` works only for 'double', and can't test `NaN` values.

Comment: There is a isnan function as well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try `isfinite`.  For example:

```
isfinite([0 1 2 inf -inf nan])
ans =
     1     1     1     0     0     0
```

Comment: ??? Undefined function or method 'isinfinite' for input arguments of type 'double'.

Error in ==> ker at 102
        if (isinfinite(M2(i,k))||isnan(M2(i,k))) I use duble values.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `isinf(x) | isnan(x)`.

The `|` is an *element-wise logical **or***. So the above command translates to *true for each element of `x` if the element is ±`Inf` or `NaN`, false otherwise*.

Comment: thanks the answer, but isinf only working on double variables

Comment: What data types are you using that aren't doubles?

Comment: i use doubles in a big 2 dimensional array.